# Is there any book or video that explains internals of webhosting?

Tags: web-hosting

I always wondered, how to setup webhosts manage the website. I wanted to know all the internals. By internals, I mean

1. How they manage so many(thousands of) websites?
2. How do they setup those? What Hardware & Softwares do they use?
3. What security issues do they deal with?
4. Setting up Cpanel/one click installer/languages etc.
5. ...
6. ...

I want to try all these things for myself first on my localhost by hacking [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) or by setting up a domain server.

If there are any blogs/videos where a real webhost is demonstrated, would be great.

In short I'm looking for **Setting up and Managing webhosting from beginners to pro**

Comment: See wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service

Comment: well, wiki article doesn't contain what I need to know

Comment: It doesn't contain easy answers for you, but the basic research is there you'll just have to do some research on your own to find out.  In it's current form your question is so subjective it's unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different topics covered in this question, I don't think you'll find just one book or blog to cover it all. In my experience even at large hosting companies there are few if any people that do it all, they have people who specialize in different areas (windows hosting, linux hosting, cloud hosting, shared hosting, dedicated hosting, security etc.) To get started I'd suggest you pick a type of hosting you're particularly interested in and go from there.

Comment: well, could you kindly point me to resources on windows shared web hosting?

Comment: I do everything I can on Linux, so unfortunately I don't have any recommendations on Windows resources. A quick Google search for "learn windows server administration" turns up some of the basics that will give you a good foundation for further research. Good luck.

Comment: You may also want to checkout, Rackspace windows cloud server knowledge base. With cloud hosting you are essentially setting up your own server to whatever specs you want and last I checked they had a pretty up to date and in depth knowledge base for Linux I would assume they have the same for windows.

Comment: In that case, point me to the information on Linux Hosting. It would give me something to start with I guess.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/index.html This will get your server installed, up and running. It will also give you an overview of what's easily available. See the docs on IPtables for introductory security (you'll want to dive deeper but this will give you a start), and the docs on virtual hosts for configuring multiple domains on one server. I'd suggest reading everything you can on Shell scripting for automating/managing the servers.

Comment: As far as Cpanel setup here's a list comparing control panel options. I have not used any of them so you'll have to test them yourself http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels